# How to install libgcrypt-1.5.3-14.el7.x86_64.rpm into my Linux conda environment (no root)

Tags: linux, package, conda, root, environment

I need to install libgcrypt-1.5.3-14.el7.x86_64.rpm into my Linux conda environment, but I do not have root permissions. I would like to ask how to manually install it, as I've tried several methods without success.

This is a meta reinforcement learning algorithmn .Below is wrong message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/yan/cemrl/analysis_runner.py", line 275, in <module>
  main()
 File "/home/yan/miniconda3/envs/test1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1137, in __call__
   return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/yan/miniconda3/envs/test1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1062, in main
   rv = self.invoke(ctx)
 File "/home/yan/miniconda3/envs/test1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
   return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
 File "/home/yan/miniconda3/envs/test1/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 763, in invoke
   return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/yan/cemrl/analysis_runner.py", line 272, in main
   analysis(variant, cemrl_compatibility)
 File "/home/yan/cemrl/analysis_runner.py", line 31, in analysis
   res = analysis(variant, cemrl_compatibility)
 File "/home/yan/cemrl/analysis_runner.py", line 42, in analysis
   initialize_networks(variant, env, experiment_log_dir)
 File "/home/yan/cemrl/philipp_runner.py", line 163, in initialize_networks
   exploration_agent = construct_exploration_agent(
 File "/home/yan/cemrl/cemrl_edited/exploration_agent.py", line 36, in construct_exploration_agent
   return EnsembleURLBAgent(num_exploration_ensemble_agents, env_name, env_args, exploration_type, experiment_log_dir, max_timesteps, exploration_pretraining_steps, showcase_itr, state_preprocessor)
 File "/home/yan/cemrl/cemrl_edited/exploration_agent.py", line 253, in __init__
   self.agents.append(URLBAgent(*args, ensemble_id=i, **kwargs))
 File "/home/yan/cemrl/cemrl_edited/exploration_agent.py", line 156, in __init__
   self.train_env = URLBAgent.URLBEnvWrapper(env, max_timesteps)
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class URLBEnvWrapper with abstract methods reset, step
```

The owner of code told me that need to install libgcrypt-1.5.3-14.el7.x86_64.rpm to solve this problem and said : "Unpack the file to the correct location. (I recall that every user has a space similar to root, which is where we store environment files when setting up our own environment.) That should do it."

Comment: `Using configure,make and make install.then add to path in vim ~/.bashrc and source it,but it was not work.` Can you give a step by step what you did (reproducible) and what `was not work` means? Do you get an error along the way or something similar?

Comment: Please add more details and include some motivation. Why do you need a version that has been EOL for ~6.5 years? Does it have to be the .rpm? Why not build from source ([tarballs](https://gnupg.org/ftp/gcrypt/libgcrypt/))?

Comment: I apologize for not providing enough detail in my description.I update the information.If there are any details that I have not explained thoroughly enough, please let me know. Thank you.